# Error Code: 1054

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with the count(*) alias when in insert it in Where...I receive the following error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'count' in 'where clause'

It is my understanding that sql reads from right to left and that is the reason for the error, but I do not know how to validate this so that I am only shown the fields that are found at the two points of the database.

this is my code...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, interests.id, entity.id, entity.name, entity.entity_type, entity.city_country_province, entity.street_address, entity.user_id, entity.descript, entity.icon, city_country_province_type.city, city_country_province_type.province, city_country_province_type.country, entity.linkout, entity.map_lng, entity.map_lat              
FROM ((interests INNER JOIN interest_entity ON interests.id = interest_entity.interet_id) 
                 INNER JOIN entity ON interest_entity.entity_id = entity.id) 
                 INNER JOIN city_country_province_type ON entity.city_country_province = city_country_province_type.id             
WHERE ((interests.id)=9) AND count >= 10 AND count <= 20
```

Comment: you're trying to count everything and use an alias in a `WHERE` clause? You should be using HAVING with `COUNT()`, not an alias, FAIK. Or your brackets are off.

Comment: But even then, it still makes no sense.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why all the `(((())))` rubbish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the condition about the alias `count` into a `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, interests.id, entity.id, entity.name, entity.entity_type, entity.city_country_province, entity.street_address, entity.user_id, entity.descript, entity.icon, city_country_province_type.city, city_country_province_type.province, city_country_province_type.country, entity.linkout, entity.map_lng, entity.map_lat              
FROM ((interests INNER JOIN interest_entity ON interests.id = interest_entity.interet_id) 
                 INNER JOIN entity ON interest_entity.entity_id = entity.id) 
                 INNER JOIN city_country_province_type ON entity.city_country_province = city_country_province_type.id             
WHERE ((interests.id)=9) 
HAVING 
    count >= 10 AND count <= 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should grup by for get the proper related  count ..use having for filter cont result (and remove unuseful () )

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
  , interests.id
  , entity.id
  , entity.name
  , entity.entity_type
  , entity.city_country_province
  , entity.street_address
  , entity.user_id
  , entity.descript
  , entity.icon
  , city_country_province_type.city
  , city_country_province_type.province
  , city_country_province_type.country
  , entity.linkout
  , entity.map_lng
  , entity.map_lat              
FROM interests INNER JOIN interest_entity ON interests.id = interest_entity.interet_id
INNER JOIN entity ON interest_entity.entity_id = entity.id
INNER JOIN city_country_province_type ON entity.city_country_province = city_country_province_type.id             
WHERE interests.id=9
GROUP BY interests.id
  , entity.id
  , entity.name
  , entity.entity_type
  , entity.city_country_province
  , entity.street_address
  , entity.user_id
  , entity.descript
  , entity.icon
  , city_country_province_type.city
  , city_country_province_type.province
  , city_country_province_type.country
  , entity.linkout
  , entity.map_lng
  , entity.map_lat   
HAVING count >= 10 AND count <= 20
```